# C# Windows Forms : BindingSource PositionChanged event not firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I've got a simple winform with a bindingSource using a List as Data. I'd like to take action whenever the binding sources position is changed. Reading up, it looks like the 'positionChanged' event is what I need. However, in my app I'm unable to get this event to fire.

There is a bindingNavigator to use the bindingSoure for navigation and (for debugging) a button that changes the current binding source position.

I've tried to simplify this as much as possible. My form code looks like this :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected List<int> data;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new List<int>();
        data.Add(4);
        data.Add(23);
        data.Add(85);
        data.Add(32);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
        bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = this.bindingSource1;            
    }

    private void bindingSource1_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Debugger breakpoint here. 
        // Expectation is this code will be executed either when
        // button is clicked, or navigator is used to change positions. 
        int x = 0; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.Position = 2;
    }
}
```

The eventHandler is autogenerated in the designer :

```
        // 
        // bindingSource1
        // 
        this.bindingSource1.PositionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.bindingSource1_PositionChanged);
```

Now, the trouble is that whenever I run this, the 'PositionChanged' event just will not trigger. I've verified that bindingSource1.Position changes based on the navigator and the button. But no matter what I do, the event won't actually trip. I'm guessing this is something pretty stupid at this point, or I'm completely misinterpreting when the event is supposed to fire.

Using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `Form_Load`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this overrides the reference you have created in the desinger.cs file
    // either remove this line 
    bindingSource1 = new BindingSource(); 
    // or add this line  
    //  bindingSource1.PositionChanged += bindingSource1_PositionChanged;
    bindingSource1.DataSource = data;
    bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = this.bindingSource1;   
}
```

When you create the the new object `new BindingSource()`, it doesn't have the event `PositionChanged` subscribed. That is why you never hit your breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jens, It appears I was not being very bright this morning. All fixed, I'll mark as answer shortly.

Comment: @Sperry my pleasure :) It is an honest mistake. I made it my self more times that I care to admit.